# Scrolling element scrollbar jumping to top after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby and i made a vertical side navigation menu. I used useRef for navigation wrapper and for every item inside menu for getting some height values. Then I calculated the scroll position for active navigation link as you can see below and set scrollTop value for navigation wrapper and i can align scroll bar to active link item.

```
 function calculateScrollPosition(wrapper, link) {
    const distance = wrapper.current.scrollHeight - wrapper.current.offsetHeight
    const scrollUnit = wrapper.current.scrollHeight / distance
    const itemOffset =
      wrapper.current.scrollHeight / 2 < link.current.offsetTop
        ? link.current.offsetTop + link.current.clientHeight
        : link.current.offsetTop - link.current.clientHeight
    const position = Math.floor(itemOffset / scrollUnit)
    wrapper.current.scrollTop = position
  }
```

and i am calling it here

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeLink) {
      calculateScrollPosition(list, activeLink)
    }
  }, [activeLink])
```

But each time I click the link inside sidebar and change the page, scrollbar of navigation jumping to top for a second and then finding the right place. I expect it to go to new position from last position, not jumping to top. Any help i will appreciated.

Comment: where are you calling "calculateScrollPosition" function?

Comment: Yes, please include the component code that is calling this so there is more context around usage and what could be happening.

Comment: @MShahzaibShoaib because i am calculating scroll position for active navigation item.

Comment: @DrewReese I am calling it inside useEffect with ref of navigation wrapper and active nav item.

Comment: You can set a scroll position to the state and then use that for setting a list scroll top.

Comment: @mkEagles i dont think you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. I actually fixed my problem so i want to explain how i did.

As i mentioned, I'm using Gatsby and i have multi-lang website. Pages creating dynamically with .md files. Gatsby re-renders when the top level component changes between pages. Actually that was broke my sidebar transitions too because it was unmount and mount layout again when i change page.

Gatsby doesn't automatically wrap pages in a layout component. So I wrapped pages with layout using [gatsby-plugin-layout](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/). I made 2 different layout. One of it main layout with sidebar and header, other one for my dynamically created pages. I can use one of inside another. Now its not re-render my main layout, it is just re-render layout which i created for pages inside main layout, scrollbar not jumping to top and transitions are works fine.

I don't know if i explained well. I hope it helps others who have the same problem.